# How can I get pointers to a variable number of arrays in unsafe C# code

Tags: c#, unsafe

If I have an array of double[,] objects where the length of the array is known in advance, then I can setup an array of pointers to the double[,] objects like this:

```
int NumMatrices = 3;
double[][,] VectorOfMatrix = new double[NumMatrices][, ];
for (int i = 0; i < VectorOfMatrix.Length; i++) VectorOfMatrix[i] = new double[10, 10];
unsafe {
    fixed (double* fpM0 = VectorOfMatrix[0], fpM1 = VectorOfMatrix[1], fpM2 = VectorOfMatrix[2]) {
        double** ppMatrix = stackalloc double*[3];
        ppMatrix[0] = fpM0;
        ppMatrix[1] = fpM1;
        ppMatrix[2] = fpM2;
        ...
    }
}
```

But if the length of the array is not known in advance, how do the equivalent thing?

Comment: in what scenario do you *need* all the pointers at once? how would you usefully use them, in this case where the length of the outer array is unknown? What are you going to be *doing* with the pointers in this case? (frankly, `unsafe` is *usually* a bad idea - and in current C#, most `fixed` blocks like this can use `Span<T>` just as readily).

Comment: @MarcGravell , I am a mathematician, and just sometimes I want to to complex mathematical calculations on big data sets which I will manually optimise for speed.  I am still using Visual Studio 2017 and Span<T> is not available in that.  Will Span<T> solve my problem?

Comment: spans *change* what is involved; it is hard to say whether it will "solve [your] problem" without seeing what is in the `...`; but what I *can* say is: if you're doing mathematics on large matrices, and you want to optimize for speed: what probably *will* help is SIMD ("vectorization"), and *that* is something that you can get for free from spans (*if* you're using up to date frameworks; the best SIMD support is in .NET Core 3.1 or above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, you can't. It is a marker on the "local" that *defines* something as being `fixed` from the perspective of the JIT, so you *need* a "local" per `fixed` element, and the number of locals is determined at compile time, not runtime.

I *suspect* you would need a locally scoped `fixed` at the call-site when you need it for that individual inner-array - but that's not very problematic: `fixed` is a *remarkably cheap* way of pinning (it is literally just a reference copy on the stack, with the JIT knowing from context that it means "pinned")

That said: I *suspect* you might also be able to use spans here, and bypass the entire need to use `fixed` or pointers.